# Error in Proc*C compilation

Tags: c++, oracle, macros, typedef, embedded-sql

I'm trying to compile .pc file on Red Hat Linux v4.1.2-44 (able to compile on HP and Solaris) with following precompiler options:

***PROCFLAGS***=**maxopencursors**=100 **PARSE**=NONE **userid**=db2poc/db2poc@mydb **VARCHAR**=YES **code**=CPP **CPP_SUFFIX**=cpp **duration**=session **sqlcheck**=full **include**=/app1/myuser/Application/Source/Header **SYS_INCLUDE**=/oradata1/ora11g/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/public,/oradata1/ora11g/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/public,/oradata1/ora11g/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/plsql/public,/oradata1/ora11g/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/xdk/include,/usr/include/c++/3.4.6/backward

The problem is, wherever there is a macro or typedef data type in EXEC SQL DECLARE SECTION, it throws an error saying ***PCC-S-02322, found undefined identifier*** for **macros** and throws the following error in case of **typedef data types**:

***PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "SHORT" when expecting one of the following:***

*auto, char, const, double, enum, extern, float, int, long,*
   *ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,*
   *OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,*
   *OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,*
   *short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,*
   *typedef, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,*
   *volatile, a typedef name, a precompiled header, exec oracle,*
   *exec oracle begin, exec, exec sql, exec sql begin,*
   *exec sql end, exec sql type, exec sql var, exec sql include,*

***The symbol "enum," was substituted for "SHORT" to continue.***

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may first precompile your source with c precompiler:

cpp -P -E yourfile.src -o yourfile.dst

Then you will get macros unpacked.

-P option is needed because Pro*C is the program which can be confused with linemarkers.

-E option is needed because Pro*C is the program which can be confused with non-traditional output.